# how to create a temporary directory inside a Java application using java 1.6 ?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a java application where i'm using javaMail API to send attachments  generated by other utilities java class.
IS there any way to create a temporary folder where to save these attachments before sending  it using java 1.6 version ?

Comment: If your other utilities are at all capable of writing to an OutputStream I would avoid creating any File at all (doing everything in memory). You could catch output data with an ByteArrayOutputStream and create the attachment(s) directly from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File.createTempFile` to create temp files which go to a temp directory (depending on your platform), but there's no way to create a temp dir in a similar way.

You should modify your generating code to create temp files instead, and then pass the `File` objects around.

Comment: Method name is createTempFile

Answer (score 0):

[Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a `Files.createTempDir()` method, explained [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#createTempDir()).

```
  /** Maximum loop count when creating temp directories. */
  private static final int TEMP_DIR_ATTEMPTS = 10000;

public static File createTempDir() {
    File baseDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    String baseName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "-";

    for (int counter = 0; counter < TEMP_DIR_ATTEMPTS; counter++) {
        File tempDir = new File(baseDir, baseName + counter);
        if (tempDir.mkdir()) {
            return tempDir;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create directory within " + TEMP_DIR_ATTEMPTS + " attempts (tried " + baseName + "0 to " + baseName + (TEMP_DIR_ATTEMPTS - 1) + ')');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to create a temp file, then delete it, then recreate it as a directory.  For example, this is how JUnit's `TemporaryFolder` Rule does it:

```
    File folder= File.createTempFile("junit", "");
    folder.delete();
    folder.mkdir();
```

However, this isn't threadsafe since something else can create the same file in the time between the `delete()` and `mkdir()` calls which will cause this code to fail.